Как вывести значение из SQLite в Python с учётом работы остальных подобных вызовов
По непонятным для меня обстоятельствам при конкретно этом взаимодействии с базой данных возникает проблема cursor.execute('UPDATE Tasks SET OnUsing = ? WHERE text_task = ?', (True, BDtask[1])) IndexError: list index out of range
                ~~

Под местом с проблемой написал "~~"
global user_role
        global us_name
        if user_role == 'Исполнитель':
            tasks = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE OnUsing = ?', ('False',))
            if list(tasks.fetchall()) != '':
                BDtask = (tasks.fetchall())
                cursor.execute('UPDATE Tasks SET OnUsing = ? WHERE text_task = ?', (True, BDtask[1]))
                cursor.execute('UPDATE Tasks SET id_userExecutor = ? WHERE text_task = ?', (us_id, BDtask[1]))
                conn.commit()
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = "текст сообщения")
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, taskMessage)
            else:
                bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, text = "текст сообщения")

Я знаю почему возникает данная ошибка, однако исходя из кода вы можете понять что таблица не пустая и в ней есть несколько вручную сделанных строк(может в этом проблема? Однако после добавления кода с автоматическим добавление строчки ситуация не решилась)
Также если вы знаете как правильнее задать вопрос чтобы ответ на него смогли найти остальные - пишите

if list(tasks.fetchall()) — первый вызов fetchall вернул все строки; BDtask = (tasks.fetchall()) — второй вызов fetchall не может ничего вернуть, потому что всё уже вернулось в первом вызове fetchall. Таким образом BDtask гарантированно является пустым списком
